# Orstein-Uhlenbeck Process with power-law-correlated noise

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Consider a noise-driven drifting system given by the Langevin Eq:

$$\dot{v}+\gamma v =\xi$$
Where $v$ denotes velocity with $\gamma$ being drift coefficient and $\xi$ a stochastic-noisy drive, but unlike Orstein-Uhlenbeck Process, $\xi 's$ are not $uncorrelated$ rather they themselves are $\frac{1}{f}$ noise with power-law autocorrelation function [recalling from Wiener-Khinchin theorem that the autocorrelation function is fourier transform of the power spectral density where $\frac{1}{f}$ noise has Power Spectral density $S(f)\propto \frac{1}{f^{\alpha}}$ with $1 \leq \alpha \leq 2$], say (assuming stationarity):

$$\langle \xi(t) \ \xi(0) \rangle = \tilde{\Gamma}|t|^{-\theta} \ \ ; \ \ \ 0 \leq \theta \leq 1$$

Therefore the velocity profile of $v(t)$ is as:

$$v(t)= \Big[ v_0 +  \int^{t}_{0}e^{\gamma t'} \xi(t')dt' \Big] e^{-\gamma t} $$ where $\langle \xi(t) \rangle = 0$ will be considered, thus the average $\langle v(t) \rangle$ is same as Orstein-Uhlenbeck case,

BUT, what about the case of average energy, or second moment $\langle v^2(t) \rangle$, i.e.:

$$\langle v^2(t) \rangle = v_0^2 e^{-2 \gamma t} + e^{- 2 \gamma t } \int^{t}_{0} dt_1 \int^{t}_{0} dt_2 e^{\gamma{(t_1 + t_2)}} \langle \xi(t_1) \xi(t_2) \rangle $$

This expression is well treatable with delta correlated gaussian white noise, but it's nontrivial here.

How do I get passed with this integral ?

$$\int^{t}_{0} dt_1 \int^{t}_{0} dt_2 e^{\gamma{(t_1 + t_2)}}|t_1 - t_2|^{-\theta} $$

I am stuck here. Kindly tell me how to handle such long-range-correlated-noisy setup.

Comment: If you do not want to calculate it numerically you may want to try using the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition).

Comment: I do see the similar form, but don't understand how that helps. Thanks!